# relatorio iReport no servidor

Tags: java, ireport

Bom dia pessoal. Estou com um problema aqui, que não achei nada na net parecido. Tenho um projeto jsf que gera um relatorio no ireport, que funciona localmente perfeitamente. Simulei um servidor local com o tomcat e tambem funcionou perfeitamente. Porem, quando subo a aplicação no servidor do meu trabalho, ele nao abre...ele abre uma nova aba igual a pagina do botao do relatorio, mas nada de erro nem do relatorio. Queria saber se alguém tem alguma sugestão ou ja passou por isso. O servidor é Windows Server 2003. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá. Seja bem vindo ao stack overflow. Tente dar mais detalhes sobre qual erro ocorre no servidor. Já tentou pegar o log do tomcat no servidor para ver o erro que ocorre ?

Comment: cara, muito obrigado, deu certo. Ja havia olhado os logs, mas com tantos deploys me confundi nos logs, ai consegui achar o certo e arrumar o erro. Obrigado mesmo

Comment: Cara veja o log, mas pelo que você narrou é provável que seja a path do jrxml ou algum subreport que ele abre.